Pebble Template - Html tags are getting visible in page
I want the list that is ownerList to be displayed one after other, for that i am using for loop in pebble engine template. But i am getting output with html tags appended.
How to display list one after other using pebble template
current output
<p>Greece </p>
<p>Anthony</p>
displaying with <p> and </p> tags
Expected Output
Greece
Anthony
I want output to print without html tags.
I have created the template
OwnerList.peb
{% for owner in ownersList%}
<p>{{ owner.dateTime }}</p>
{% endfor %}

Code
PebbleEngine engine = new PebbleEngine.Builder().build();
PebbleTemplate compiledTemplate = 
engine.getTemplate("OwnerList.peb");

Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<>();
context.put("ownerList", ownerList);

Writer writer = new StringWriter();
compiledTemplate.evaluate(writer, context);

String output = writer.toString();


It is HTML you are generating what would you expect...

displaying with  and  tags -- displaying it where? Browser? Console? Text editor? Something else?

@tevemadar displaying in browser.  Inside HTML page there is div, inside div is populated with the content of the OwnerList.peb however it is not being encoded as HTML but it's displaying Greece when I want it to display as Greece

@M. Deinum issue is HTML is not getting encoded. It is showing the html tags.

What does your controller look like? Post the full controller not just snippets of code. You are either using @RestController returning a String which will do just that return a String or have set the content type to text/plain when using an @Controller. Anyway to get a better understanding we need the full controller. Also if this is using Spring you should really be using a ViewResolver and View implementation for this instead of putting this inside a controller.

I assume you're using  output as a value for another template?

Wherever you define {{ ownerList }} you should use {{ ownerList | raw }} instead.
